# How to check if a folder is empty

Tags: android

I currently need to send files from a folder, i want the service i am running to check in the folder every half an hour....how am i able to know if the folder is clear?

Comment: i think there maybe an is exist method?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
File directory = new File("/path/to/folder");
File[] contents = directory.listFiles();
// the directory file is not really a directory..
if (contents == null) {

}
// Folder is empty
else if (contents.length == 0) {

}
// Folder contains files
else {

}
```

Comment: Would be nice to be able to check emptiness, or number of files, without having to load them all into memory. But alas.

Comment: John is right, we should check if it is directory first.

Comment: a much more elegant solution is by using FileObserver

Answer (score 7):

```
if (file.isDirectory()) {
    String[] files = file.list();
    if (files.length == 0) {
        //directory is empty
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have the path, you can make a File object check for entries (using file.isDirectory() and file.list())